# I want Selenium without tests

Tags: java, selenium

I've spent a lot of time writing Selenium scripts, and more recently, I've been using Selenium to automate repetitive processes I use a web browser to accomplish at work.

I really wish I could write Selenium scripts without the need for a `@Test` annotation, or even better, any testing framework. I have done my fair share of research into the question, but they always point back to the same "Getting started writing tests with Selenium!" pages.

So what do I use to automate web processes?

Comment: You can't have looked too hard because most of the links I come across don't use testing frameworks. You can look at the Selenium Java docs and none of them use a test framework.

Comment: @JeffC I've tried searches for "Selenium no tests" or whatnot. I guess I never actually read a bunch of Selenium source code? I think this is a legitimate question who's answer should be more obviously fronted, "Hey, you don't need test methods". Can't find a source that says that or examples using Selenium as an automation service as opposed to a testing service. Id enjoy this not being closed as a reference for myself and others.

Comment: I've tried more and more searches. Everyone uses Selenium as a test library it seems, which is understadnable seeing that was the entire point of Selenium's development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for @Test, just write your usual Selenium code in your standalone application. For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
    driver.quit();
}
```

Run as an executable jar, run in a Groovy script, the possibilities are endless!